# How to create classes based on an integer entered by a user

Tags: python, class, python-3.8

Is it possible to create the same class multiple times with user input in python 3.8?

For example I may write:

```
x = input('Enter an int:')
```

Is it possible to create x classes automatically.  Not instances but actual classes?

Comment: yes, what is the problem?

Comment: [Yes, this is possible](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html). But that sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: What 3 classes do you want to create, should `x == 3`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah why not...

```
>>> def mkClass(i):
...     class mk:
...             def __init__(self):
...                     self.val = i
...     return(mk)
...
>>> ok = mkClass(7)
>>>
>>> a = ok()
>>> a.val
7
>>>
```